# Place markers on map with timer

Tags: android, google-maps, timer, google-maps-markers, timertask

I'm adding markers (around 200) as a path on map using google maps v2, and perfectly placed on map.
but my requirement is to add each marker with some time interval so i wanted it to look like some animation. so i've tried two methods,
First method is

```
latvalues[] = {....};
longvalues[]={....};
for(int i=0;i<latvalues.length;i++){
   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latvalues[i],longvalues[i])).title("Info")
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img)));
Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

this is not working, only after placing all markers, map is loading..

Second method is

```
 latvalues[] = {....};
longvalues[]={....};
Timer marktimer = new Timer();
markTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

    for(int i=0;i<latvalues.length;i++){
   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latvalues[i],longvalues[i])).title("Info")
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img)));
    }
}
},0, 500);

marktimer.cancel();
```

this is not even loading any markers also...

Please suggest any workaround to achieve this...

Edited code using Countdown timer:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.datemap);

    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.busmap);
    map=fm.getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    countdown();
}
public void countdown(){
    if(this.ctimer != null){
        this.ctimer.cancel();
    }
    this.ctimer = new CountDownTimer(1000,500) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(markerno<latitudeValues1.length){
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeValues1[markerno],longitudevalues1[markerno])).title("Info")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
                markerno++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitudeValues1[markerno],longitudevalues1[markerno]), 12));
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: higher your time new CountDownTimer(10000,500)

Comment: @A.S. even though only one point showing up!!

Comment: solved the problem using broadcast receiver..by broadcasting in receiver to same activity and thread.sleep in between each broadcast to add marker..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it with a CountdownTimer?

```
int markerNo = 0;
public void startCountDown(){       
    if(this._countDownTimer != null){
        this._countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    this._countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(TIME_FOR_SET_IN_S * 1000, 500){

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            if(markerNo < longvalues.size()){
                             map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latvalues[markerNo],longvalues[markerNo])).title("Info")
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img)));
                              markerNo++
                            }

        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this method also, showing one marker only but no hang in screen and no other markers..

Comment: are u incrementing a value in the onTick to get the next lat/long from your array?

Comment: no, i've kept count down timer inside FOR loop.. just adding marker in onTick method...

Comment: What the hell are you doing ;) No for loop, add a marker every tick and increment a integer to get the next marker!

Comment: removed FOR loop, still showing only first marker. its not calling ontick again.. :(

Comment: What is yor TIME_TO_SET??

Comment: i need 500 millisec, so i gave 500,200 in method

Answer (score 1):

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Runnable worker = new Runnable() {
    private int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // add marker with index i
        i++;
        if (i < latvalues.length) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    }
};
```

start (or resume after pausing) adding `Marker`s with:

```
handler.post(worker);
```

pause with:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(worker);
```

Note: as always, you need to have `removeCallbacks` call in your code to avoid leaking `Activity`.

Comment: please dont mind, i never used handlers, can u specify where to start and pause the handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
final Handler _han = new Handler();
for(int i = 1;i<=50;i++)
{
_han.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    yourMethodToAddMarker();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }, 2000); //

}
```

Comment: try to remove call back of that handler like @MaciejGórski said